# Parse metadata json from docker bake github action

Tags: json, docker-compose, github-actions

I need to grab the outputs from the `metadata` output on the docker/bake action: https://github.com/docker/bake-action#outputs

Here's the bake action:

```
      - name: Build all Dockerfiles images listed in docker-compose.yml
        uses: docker/bake-action@v2.3.0
        id: monorepo-build
        env:
          ....
        with:
          push: true
          files: docker-bake.hcl
          set: |
            *.args.environment=${{ steps.vars.outputs.env }}
            *.args.site=${{ inputs.SITE }}
            *.args.GH_PACKAGE_READ=${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
```

Then immediately after I run:

```
      - name: Test getting the metadata output from Bake step 
        run: |
          touch metadata.json
          echo "${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}" > metadata.json
          cat metadata.json | jq '.mykey'
```

So as you see I've tried to echo the metadata into a json file first and then parse that using `jq` to get the top level key `mykey`. I've also tried to parse directly by echoing `"${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}" |  jq '.mykey'`

I'm getting the error `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 8`. Here's the JSON output from the file:

```
{
    mykey: {
        containerimage.buildinfo: {
            frontend: dockerfile.v0,
            attrs: {
                ...
            sources: [{
                ...
            }]
        },
        containerimage.descriptor: {
            mediaType: ********
            digest: **********
            size: 856
        },
        containerimage.digest: *****************
        image.name: ****************
    }
}
```

I've noticed it doesn't have double quotes around the key/value pairs. When I add double quotes on in my local copy and run `jq` it seems fine.

How can I sort this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the double quotes (`""`) in your `echo`, this:

```
echo "${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}"
```

would lead to something like:

```
echo "{
    "mykey": {
        "containerimage.buildinfo": {
            "frontend": "dockerfile.v0,"
            "attrs": {
```

So the fix is to either use single quotes:

```
  - name: Test getting the metadata output from Bake step 
    run: |
      touch metadata.json
      echo '${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}' > metadata.json
      cat metadata.json | jq '.mykey'
```

or use `cat`:

```
- name: Test getting the metadata output from Bake step 
  run: |
    cat << EOF >  metadata.json
    ${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}
    EOF
    
    cat metadata.json | jq '.mykey'
```

Or maybe a different approach as [Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) mentioned in the comments:

```
  - name: Test getting the metadata output from Bake step 
    run: |
      jq '.myKey' <<< $METADATA > some-output.json
    env:
      METADATA: ${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}
```

Comment: Good catch! Is that a redundant single quote in your `cat` example? Another alternative could be to set it as an env var under `env: METADATA: ${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}` and then use it in bash `echo "$METADATA" > metadata.json`.

Comment: Another alternative without file: `jq '.mykey' <<< "$METADATA"`

Comment: Brilliant! the env variable with `jq '.mykey' <<< "$METADATA"` looks cleaner to me, thank you

Comment: Great thank you! I will give this a go tomorrow :)

Comment: @Fcmam5: Typo! Replace `$VAR` with `"$METADATA"` in the last part.

Comment: Yet another possibility, avoiding an intermediate file or env var: `echo '${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}' | jq '.mykey'` or, if you like here-strings better, `jq '.mykey' <<< '${{ steps.monorepo-build.outputs.metadata }}'`